# Activating a query from a checked checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a basic form with just 1 text area and a submit button. Once submitted, it sends the name entered into a MySQL table.

The table structure is; **ID , name , score**,

The ID is AI. The name is user input and the score has a default of 0.

Then, I have an output page, which is where I need the help. On the output page, I have made my connection checked my connection caught my ASSOC's array and dropped it into a little HTML table to keep it organised, and I have added a checkbox to the end of each row.

Now, what I'm trying to do is: when any of the checkboxes are checked, I need a query to run to add 1 to the current value of score in the record.

Here is my code so far and YES it is very basic so far and it does work. I know I have to add some security to it and a lot of formatting but those can happen once I get the project working....

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> DaTaBaSe CoNeCtIoN TeStInG PaGe </title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="000000">
<font color="FF0000">

<?php
include ('conection.php');



//define $result as $con and run the query $sql 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//if number of rows in the table is higher 0 draw the table 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo 
"<table border= 5 bordercolor= #0000FF><tr><th><font       color=#FF0000>ID</th><th><font color=#FF0000>Name</th></tr>";
//output the data
  while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
      //add the results to populate the table 
      echo "<tr><td><font color= #FF0000>".$row  [id]."</td><td><font color= #FF0000>".$row["name"]."</td><td><font color= #FF0000>".$row["score"]."</td><td><input type= checkbox name=win>".$row["win"]."</td></tr>";
      }
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results found";
}

 $conn->close();
 ?>

</font>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: How are you sending this data? In a Form?

Comment: What's the error? What did you try to achieve your requirement? Post the code that's not working!

Comment: I did not really get any further with the code than this there is no error to report on as the code you see is everything so far this is the total beginning for this project,

Comment: it would be an insult to all programmers out there to call me a programmer I am a novice to all of this stuff,